# Excel VBA that make copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook, that has some sheets, Main one called: Start Here, I have an option once I click it, it will unhide sheet called T, getting most data from the Start Here (after I enter the data). Now I made the code below to copy T sheet and call it T2, T3 .... as much as I click copy. At the same time in the Sheet (Start Here) it copies range M4:V31 to next empty column which will be: W4:AF31 and so on:

The code is:

```
Function SheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not Sheets(sheetName) Is Nothing
End Function

Sub CreateNewT()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    
    'Find the next available T sheet number
    While SheetExists("T" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    'Create a new T sheet and copy the contents from the original T sheet
    Sheets("T").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "T" & i
    
    'Copy the specified range to the next available column on the Start Here sheet
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = Sheets("Start Here").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Sheets("Start Here").Range("M4:V31").Copy
    Sheets("Start Here").Cells(4, lastCol + 9).PasteSpecial
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q7:AF31")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lastCol As Integer
        lastCol = Sheets("T").Cells(21, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Dim sheetNum As Integer
        sheetNum = lastCol - 20
        If SheetExists("T" & sheetNum) Then
            GetRangeForT(sheetNum).Value = Sheets("Start Here").Range("Q7:AF31").Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Function GetRangeForT(sheetNumber As Integer) As Range
    Select Case sheetNumber
        Case 2
            Set GetRangeForT = Sheets("Start Here").Range("W4:AF31")
        Case Else
            Set GetRangeForT = Sheets("Start Here").Range("Q7:R16")
    End Select
End Function

Function GetTSheetForCell(cell As Range) As Worksheet
    Dim tSheet As Worksheet
    Set tSheet = Nothing
    
    If Not Intersect(cell, Range("AA7:AM16")) Is Nothing Then 'Change AA7:AM16 to the range you want to monitor
        Dim tSheetName As String
        tSheetName = "T" & Mid(cell.Address, 2, 1)
        Set tSheet = Sheets(tSheetName)
    End If
    
    Set GetTSheetForCell = tSheet
End Function

Function GetTCellForCell(cell As Range, tSheet As Worksheet)

Sub CopyAndUpdate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsStartHere As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim rngPaste As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsStartHere = wb.Sheets("Start Here")
    Set rngCopy = wsStartHere.Range("A21:J30")
    
    ' Copy and paste the data to a new range in the Start Here sheet
    Set rngPaste = wsStartHere.Range("AA7")
    rngCopy.Copy
    rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    ' Loop through each sheet in the workbook and update the formulas in the specified ranges
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Start Here" Then
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "T2"
                    Set rngCopy = wsStartHere.Range("AA7:AB16")
                    Set rngPaste = ws.Range("A21:B30")
                Case "T3"
                    Set rngCopy = wsStartHere.Range("AC7:AD16")
                    Set rngPaste = ws.Range("A21:B30")
                ' Add more cases for additional sheets as needed
            End Select
            
            ' Update the formulas in the specified ranges
            For i = 0 To 1
                ws.Cells(31 + i, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!" & rngCopy.Cells(i + 17, 1).Address(False, False) & "),"""",'Start Here'!" & rngCopy.Cells(i + 17, 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
                ws.Cells(31 + i, 2).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!" & rngCopy.Cells(i + 17, 2).Address(False, False) & "),"""",'Start Here'!" & rngCopy.Cells(i + 17, 2).Address(False, False) & ")"
            Next i
            
            ' Optional: Uncomment the following line to calculate the formulas
            ' ws.Calculate
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Optional: Uncomment the following line to clear the clipboard
    ' Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Now the only thing I need its to Sheet T2, T3 .... get the data from new range pasted in the Start Here sheet. as following:

```
In the Sheet T: Range (A21:B30) getting data from (Start Here) sheet Range: (Q7:R16)
A31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!Q17),"",'Start Here'!Q17)
A32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!Q18),"",'Start Here'!Q18)
B31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!R17),"",'Start Here'!R17)
B32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!R18),"",'Start Here'!R18)

Range (E21:F30) from (Start Here) sheet Range: (S7:T16)
E31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!S17),"",'Start Here'!S17)
E32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!S18),"",'Start Here'!S18)
F31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!T17),"",'Start Here'!T17)
F32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!T18),"",'Start Here'!T18)

Range (I21:J30) from (Start Here) sheet Range: (U7:V16)
I31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!U17),"",'Start Here'!U17)
I32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!U18),"",'Start Here'!U18)
J31 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!V17),"",'Start Here'!V17)
J32 has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!V18),"",'Start Here'!V18)

I need same as T sheet, other sheets like T2 and T3 getting data from new range pasted in the Start here)
For Example:
T2 sheet created, and Range W4:AF31 created also.
In the T2 Sheet range (A21:B30) getting data from (Start Here) sheet Range: (AA7:AB16)
And 
A31 should has this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!AA17),"",'Start Here'!AA17)
A32 should this function: =IF(ISBLANK('Start Here'!AA18),"",'Start Here'!AA18)
And so on
```

I can't get the correct one, can you help me with full code? Thanks